# How to attach an image in MMS programmatically in android

Tags: android, image, sms, mms

I have tried the following but none of them are reaching my goal.

following code showing a chooser.

```
 Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
            mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            mmsIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

following code shows compose message view, but image is not attached.

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));//Uri.parse(url));
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + "89565656"));
        startActivity(smsIntent);
```

But,
    I need the message compose view with my image from sd card.
How to achieve this.

Thank you in advance...!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//file is the file on the SD Card
mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.toURL().toString()));
mmsIntent.setType("image/png");//mmsIntent.setType("image/*"); Maybe?
startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this code also showing a chooser.

Comment: Hm, the activity you need is the 
com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.(see LogCat when you compose new mms) You can't get direct access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code if don't want to open chooser and directly attach image

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     


    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
         ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
         String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;

         if(packageName.contains("mms")) {
             Log.d("TAG", packageName + " : " + ri.activityInfo.name);
             sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
         }
    } 

    sendIntent.putExtra("address", "1234567890");
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg"));
    sendIntent.setType("image/*"); 
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```